# Why Mysql do not recognize pasted quote mark from Word

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

When I wrote a query in Word and pasted in the MySQL, it shows the following error and does not recognize the quote mark. I have to type in the quote mark in the query line. Why MySQL does not recognize the ' or " from Word format but all other characters are fine? Thanks!

```
SELECT  S1.Sno, S1.Sname, S1.Sdept
FROM     student S1, student S2
WHERE  S1.Sdept = S2.Sdept  AND S2.Sname = ‘Ahn’
 LIMIT 0, 25

 #1054 - Unknown column 'â€˜Ahnâ€™' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: why you want to use Word? it applies formatting on text there. you can use notepad.

Comment: Because `‘` is not the same as `'` and only the latter is allowed

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and answers!! I did not realize that SQL use ' before the string and the same ' afterward. Instead of notepad, I ma looking for a platform to write dummy SQL syntax--similar to using Rstudio for R and Jupyter Notebook for Python. This way, i can write and excucute without switching screen. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are different characters. You can go into Word and adjust the settings so it uses "straight" quotes rather than the curly quotes.

Why doesn't MySQL recognize the characters?  Well, they are not part of the 128-character ASCII 7-bit set.  That is the set of characters that has traditionally been used to define the constructs of programming languages.  At the time that MySQL was invented, I believe there were multiple competing methods of representing wider characters, and there was definitely no requirement to support the particular methods used by MS Word.

Let me also add that MS Word is not a good tool for developing SQL code, so supporting it seems utterly unnecessary.